# How do i set two pictures on the same line using html and css?

Tags: html, css

Here's my code in html:

```
<div id="pictures">

   <div class="pic1"> 
   <img src="something.jpg" width=200px; height=200px" 
   </div>

   <div class="pic2"> 
   <img src="something.jpg" width=200px; height=200px" 
   </div> 
   

</div>
```

I want to put these two pictures on the same line.

The only thing that worked was when i changed 'div' class into 'span' class, then the two pics appeared next to each other, but then i couldn't put any space in between them no matter what i tried.

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `.pic1, .pic2{display:inline-block;}`

Comment: You've wrapped each picture in its own `<div>`, which is a block element. The easiest way to accomplish that is simply not doing this.

Comment: I tried the {display:inline-block;} like 50 times now - IT DOESN'T WORK.

Comment: But if i wrap both pics into the same class, how do i work on the two pics separately then? Like if i want to turn them into hyperlinks etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try using single div for both image
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML>

<head>

<title>nanda</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nandacss.css" />

</head>


<body>

<br>

<p style="color:red">Pick one</p> 


<div id="pictures">

<div class="pic1"> <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Trulli" width=200px; height=200px />  

<img src="//via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Trulli" width=200px; height=200px> </div>

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works. BUT why doesn't the other one work? What is the reason? Also, how do i now add space between the two pics? And, what if i want to turn the two pics into hyperlinks, how do i do that now that they are both under the same class?

Comment: you can delete the spaces if you like and to use the hyper link just put anchor tag outside both image. like
<a href="http://google.com"> <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Trulli" width=200px; height=200px /> </a> 
if you like the answer accept as the answer. thank you

Comment: How do i add space between the two pics was my question, not how do i remove the space. There is NO space currently.

Comment: oh sorry my bad.just use margin in your css.

Comment: how do i use the margin!?

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the inner `<div>`s. `<div>`s (and their contents) always appear in different lines because they are block-level elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>nanda</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nandacss.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p style="color: red;">Pick one</p> 

  <div id="pictures">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200" width="200px" height="200px">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200" width="200px" height="200px">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But if i put the two pics under the same class or id, how can i work on them separately? Like if i want to turn them into hyperlinks etc?

Comment: You can set the `id` or `class` attributes directly in the images. (Or you can wrap them in `<span>`s or use other solutions posted here.)

Answer (score 0):

```
.pic1,
.pic2 {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

You can then add your spacing between the elements too.

Run Code Snippet to see CSS aligning the two images:

```css
.pic1,
.pic2 {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p style="color:red">Pick one</p> 


<div id="pictures">

<div class="pic1"> <img src="something.jpg" width=200px; height=200px" /> </div>

<div class="pic2"> <img src="something.jpg" width=200px; height=200px" /> </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried this 20 times and it does not work. Why? I don't get it. It doesn't freaking work. What am i doing wrong!?

Comment: @TaishoMori I have edited my answer to include a runnable code snippet of the change displaying the images side by side